# PHP has to save JSON String first and open it again, to work with it

Tags: php, json

I'm having the strangest behavior and I was working on it for a few hours now. I'm sending a large and complex JSON string via AJAX to my server and when I decode it, I cannot access its elements. But when I go ahead and save the decoded JSON string to a file and open it again, I am suddenly able to  work with its elements. I just cannot explain this behavior. Here's my code.

***This does not work***

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$json = $_POST['json'];
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
// At this point I cannot work with the $obj elements
```

***This works***

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$json = $_POST['json'];
$data = json_decode($json, true);

file_put_contents( 'test.txt', $data);
$file = file_get_contents('test.txt');
$obj = json_decode($file);
// At this point I can work with the $obj elements
```

Please Note, that I need the header, because I get the JSON from a different server.

Comment: how can you not work with the object? What's its content?

Comment: It almost sounds like like maybe the json string you want is actually the string value of a property in a another JSON object that **is** successfully decoded. ie. `$data` looks like this when decoded: `Array ( 'someKey' => '{"someOtherKey":"someValue"}' )`. Can you post a dump of `$_POST['json'] and `$data` with any private details masked out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your json is double encoded, that is it works when you decode it twice. Try

```
$obj = json_decode(json_decode($json, true));
```

Answer (score 2):

in your first trial you used:

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
```

The true is converting to array not object